# How to use getElementByID in JavaScript to connect to my HTML drop down box?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a drop-down box in HTML showing three options. I am also using javaScript and want to use the getElementById tool to connect the two. However, I only have one ID for the drop-down box. How does javascript recognize that I have three different options?

Comment: Hi; welcome to stack overflow. It’s important when answering questions that you provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example to that end, please post samples of your code.

Comment: As suggested previously, please share some snippets of your code and try to explain what you are trying to achieve and the issues you are facing.

Answer (score 1):

There's actually a [demo on w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_select_get) showing exactly what you're asking. To get the number of options, you could do something like

```
document.getElementById("mySelect").options.length
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how to retrieve the value of a dropdown: https://jsfiddle.net/ykcwgnm8/

You use `getElementBy*` functions to get the element, however `value` attribute denotes which item is currently selected.

HTML:

```
<select id="dropdown">
    <option value="1">First option</option>
    <option value="2">Second option</option>
    <option value="3">Third option</option>
</select>
```

JS:

```
function onChangeHandler(e)
{
    alert("you have selected item with value "+this.value);
}
document.getElementById("dropdown").addEventListener("change", onChangeHandler);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can listen for change like this

```js
var list = document.getElementById("mySelect")

list.addEventListener('change', function(e){
  
  console.log(e.target.selectedIndex)
  console.log(e.target.options[e.target.selectedIndex].text)
})
```

```html
<select id="mySelect">
  <option>Apple</option>
  <option>Orange</option>
  <option>Pineapple</option>
  <option>Banana</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this, here is an example:-

html

```
<select id="selectBox">
  <option value="1">option 1</option>
  <option value="2" selected="selected">option 2</option>
  <option value="3">option 3</option>
</select>
```

js

```
var e = document.getElementById("selectBox");
var selectedValue = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
// this will give selectedValue as 2
```

Hope you find this useful!!